# Removing whitespace from title (in head)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a "wierd" issue. My output html title element creates linebreakes and whitespace.

```
<title>

    Title | Brand name

</title>
```

I use MVC 2 and got the following code to generate my title elements

**Site.Master**

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></title>
```

**Page (aspx)**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%= Html.SeoTitle(Model.MetaTitle.Trim(), Html.DefaultTitle())%>   
</asp:Content>
```

**Helper**

```
public static string SeoTitle(this HtmlHelper helper, string title, string separator, bool siteNameLast, string fallbackTitle)
        {
            var siteName = SiteName(helper);

            title = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) ? title : fallbackTitle;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteName))
                return title;

            title = title.TextToEntity();
            title = siteNameLast ? string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", title, separator, siteName) : string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", siteName, separator, title);

            return title;
         }
```

I'm can't find anything related to why I get this result. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Applying the answers will reduce one line-break, to have the output look like bellow. Can I make it on the same line?

```
<title>
    title | brand name
</title>
```

Comment: They're considered as trailing spaces in HTML, browser will not render them. Why would you care about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code causes the line breaks and white space:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%= Html.SeoTitle(Model.MetaTitle.Trim(), Html.DefaultTitle())%>   
</asp:Content>
```

If you strip the start and end tags of them, you still start and end with a line break.

```
(removed tag, still whitespace hereafter)
    <%= Html.SeoTitle(Model.MetaTitle.Trim(), Html.DefaultTitle())%>   
(removed tag, still whitespace before)
```

So the solution is to immediately start the inner content of the `asp:Content` tag without line breaks for layout.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server"><%= Html.SeoTitle(Model.MetaTitle.Trim(), Html.DefaultTitle())%></asp:Content>
```

As far as I know, this doesn't influence how the title is actually rendered. The whitespace is trimmed off the title.

Comment: It kinda does remove one issue of line-breaks, but check my edited question please.

Comment: Is that really in the generated source code, or just your browser's console? Does it matter at all since whitespace is truncated?

Comment: both looking in the source code and browser console, same result. I dont think it does matter for SEO purpose at all, just our seo guy made points regarding this. I also would like to know if I'm already working on the issue :)

Comment: It doesn't matter for SEO. Who says so?

Comment: I don't belive it does. For me know it's more of a thing I would like to solve and get why it does like that. Can't MVC make titles in one line?

Comment: Not sure I follow you with isn't MVC?

Comment: It is not, you use ASPX sites, with ASPX syntax. Master pages, etc. all ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: Well the solution is a MVC 2 project, so it's not Web Forms in that sense, MVC still has master page. But does that matter for the question?

Comment: No, but you asked if MVC can do that. And it can, but you are using the WF render engine, so nothing MVC here (besides your project structure).

Comment: Not sure, since it mangles the HTML. There are more layout issues with WF, so not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Remove whitespaces here:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server"><%= Html.SeoTitle(Model.MetaTitle.Trim(), Html.DefaultTitle())%></asp:Content>
```

Comment: That is exactly my answer from 3 minutes ago.

Comment: ... And you should guess, that my browser failed to load new answers and I didn't noticed that =\